# CSS menu doesn't work in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I know this has been asked many times, but I cannot seem to get anything to work.

My CSS Drop down seems to work in every browser except IE8  ...

I've tried added fiddling with it and I cannot get it to work

The main index.html shows the menu just fine, soon as you click a link it sends you to the page and displays inline no css styling.

http://www.qsoftsolutions.com/index.html

heres the code css and html

```css
#menu_wrap {
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
  text-align:center; 
  width:100%;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}



#menu {
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
  width:1000px;
  text-align:center; 
  margin:0 auto;
  height:61px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}


nav > ul {margin: 0}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;

  nav ul li:hover > ul {

    display: block;
  }

  nav ul {

    background: #bbb38f; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #bbb38f 0%, #6b6441 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#bbb38f), color-stop(100%,#6b6441)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #bbb38f 0%,#6b6441 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #bbb38f 0%,#6b6441 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #bbb38f 0%,#6b6441 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #bbb38f 0%,#6b6441 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bbb38f', endColorstr='#6b6441',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

    padding: 0px 2px;
    list-style:none;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-table;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Copperplate Gothic Light,Georgia, Palatino, Times New Roman, serif; 
    font-size:17px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:light;
    outline:none; 


  }
  nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
  }


  nav ul li {
    float: left;
  }

  nav ul li:hover {
    background: #736e57;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #BBB38F 0%, #6B6441 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BBB38F4 0%, #6B64415 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BBB38F 0%,#6B6441 40%);
    text-decoration:none; 
    font-family:Copperplate Gothic Light,Georgia, Palatino, Times New Roman, serif; 
    font-size:17px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:light;
    outline:none;



  }

  nav ul li:hover a {
    color:#FFFFFF;


  }

  nav ul li a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 42px;
    text-decoration:none;


  }



  nav ul li:hover > ul {
    background: #303030;
    text-decoration:none;
    display: block;

  }

  nav ul ul {
    background: #303030;

    font-family:  WalkwayBlack, Copperplate Gothic Light, Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.06em; 
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:light;
    outline:none;
    filter:alpha(opacity=95);
    opacity: 0.95;
    -moz-opacity:0.95;

  }

  nav ul ul li {
    text-decoration:none;
    float: none; 
    position: relative;

  }
  nav ul ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    color:#000;


  } 
  nav ul ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #736e57;


  }

  nav ul ul {

    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;



  }

  nav ul ul li {
    width:200px;
    float: none; 
    position: relative;

  }
  nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 5px;
    color:#000;
    font-family:  WalkwayBlack, Copperplate Gothic Light, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.06em;
    text-align: left;


  } 
  nav ul ul li a:hover {
    font-family:  WalkwayBlack, Copperplate Gothic Light, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.06em;
    text-align: left;
    background: rgb(187,179,143); /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(187,179,143,1) 0%, rgba(174,175,151,1) 38%, rgba(168,164,149,1) 62%, rgba(107,100,65,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(187,179,143,1)), color-stop(38%,rgba(174,175,151,1)), color-stop(62%,rgba(168,164,149,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(107,100,65,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(187,179,143,1) 0%,rgba(174,175,151,1) 38%,rgba(168,164,149,1) 62%,rgba(107,100,65,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(187,179,143,1) 0%,rgba(174,175,151,1) 38%,rgba(168,164,149,1) 62%,rgba(107,100,65,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(187,179,143,1) 0%,rgba(174,175,151,1) 38%,rgba(168,164,149,1) 62%,rgba(107,100,65,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(187,179,143,1) 0%,rgba(174,175,151,1) 38%,rgba(168,164,149,1) 62%,rgba(107,100,65,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bbb38f', endColorstr='#6b6441',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    color:#000;

  }

  nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%; top:0;

  }
```

```html
<!-- START MENU NAV BAR CODE -->
<div id="menu_wrap">
  <div id="menu">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Company/company.html">Company</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="Company/mission.html"><span><img src="Icons/mission.png" alt="mission" />&nbsp;Mission</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="Company/philosophy.html"><span><img src="Icons/philosophy.png" alt="Philosophy" />&nbsp;Philosophy</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Solutions/solutions.html">Solutions</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="Solutions/QPipe-Estimator/qpipe-estimator.html"><span><img src="Icons/qpipe.png" alt="qpipe" />&nbsp;Q Pipe Estimator &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <img src="Icons/arrow-small.png" alt="qpipe" /></span></a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="Solutions/QPipe-Estimator/advantage.html"><span><img src="Icons/advantage.png" alt="Advantage" />&nbsp;Advantage</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="Solutions/QPipe-Estimator/differentiator.html"><span><img src="Icons/differentiator.png" alt="Differentiator" />&nbsp;Differentiator</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="Solutions/QPipe-Estimator/features.html"><span><img src="Icons/features.png" alt="Features" />&nbsp;Features</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="Solutions/QPipe-Estimator/screenshots.html"><span><img src="Icons/screenshots.png" alt="ScreenShots" />&nbsp;Screen Shots</span></a></li>
              </ul>
          </ul>
        </li>
        </li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Services/technical-support.html"><span><img src="Icons/techsupport.png" alt="TechnicalSupport" />&nbsp;Technical Support</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="Services/training.html"><span><img src="Icons/training.png" alt="Training" />&nbsp;Training</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="Services/customization.html"><span><img src="Icons/customize.png" alt="Customization" />&nbsp;Customization</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="Services/faqs.html"><span><img src="Icons/faq.png" alt="FAQs" />&nbsp;FAQ's</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Industry</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Industry/focus.html"><span><img src="Icons/focus.png" alt="focus" />&nbsp;Focus</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="Industry/customers.html"><span><img src="Icons/customer.png" alt="customer" />&nbsp;Customers</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Contact/contact-information.html">Contact</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Contact/contact-information.html"><span><img src="Icons/mail.png" alt="ContactInformation" />&nbsp;Contact Information</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="Contact/request-information.html"><span><img src="Icons/information.png" alt="RequestInformation" />&nbsp;Request Information</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://web.qsoftsolutions.com/">Login</a>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</div>
<!-- END MENU NAV BAR CODE -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gramw/LZAFK/

Answer (score 1):

You will need a html5 shiv to make IE8 (and any other version older than IE9) recognise HTMl5 elements.

[This html5shiv script](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) will do it for you, and as the page says you use it like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```